# how can i force to make it to only string

Tags: python, operators, new-operator

Hello How can i force to make the nname to only string input because even though i put number it still continue to the next function and i only like it to be a name of the people nname= str(input()) does not work thats why im asking if there is other alternative to make it work with only a string

```
 print("Good Day Welcome To our Shop.")
mnu = ["Milktea","Foods", "Drinks", "Dessert"]
lsa = ["1.Matcha", "Taro", "Winter Melon", "Okinawa", "Chocolate",
     "Cheese Cake"]
fds  = {'Chicken'}
shot = ["tubig"]
mtms = ["ice cream"]
laht = []

print("Hi what would you like to be called, "
  "So we can inform you if your order is ready")


def cstmrinfo(name):

print("Okay " + name, "So what would you like to get " )
print(*mnu,sep = "\n")
nname=  input().lower()

def kuha_order():
 while True:
    order = input()

    if (order == "Milktea") or (order == "milktea"):
        print(lsa)
        laht.append(order)
        break
    elif (order == "Foods") or (order == "foods"):
        print(fds)
        laht.append(order)
        break
    elif (order == "Drinks") or (order == "drinks"):
         print(shot)
         laht.append(order)
         break
    elif (order == "Dessert") or (order == "dessert"):
         print(mtms)
         laht.append(order)
         break
    else:
     print("Sorry you input a thing that is not available on our menu,  "
           "Please Try again:")
     continue


def pnglhtn():
   while True:
    print("I Would like to get a: ")
    qwe = input()
    if qwe in lsa:
     print(qwe)
    elif qwe in fds:
        print(qwe)
    elif qwe in shot:
        print(qwe)
    elif qwe in mtms:
        print(qwe)
    else:
        print("There is no such thing like that ")
        continue

    dmi = int(input("How Many Servings Would you Like: "))
    laht.append(qwe)
    laht.append(dmi)
    print("So " + pngln, "you Like a " + str(laht[:2]))
    print (dmi, "Serves of: " + str(laht[:2]))
    break
cstmrinfo(nname)
kuha_order()
pnglhtn()
```

Comment: Did you mean: `if order.lower() == "milktea":`?

Comment: Please check the indentation, `def kuha_order()` looks suspect

Comment: its below one or literally the def kuha_order() if i try to space it first space is unexpected indent but as i space it the continue below the else will be the error and it shows Statement expected, found Py:DEDENT

Comment: no what i meant is when user either input Milktea or milktea it will still continue to print the flavors in this code if i put milktea it will be error not counted so you need to input the proper spelling of the Milktea that is in the list so you can see the flavors

Comment: Are `milktea` , `MilkTea`, `MILKTEA`, `MiLkTeA` and so on correct inputs?

Comment: no but i want to make it like that

Answer (score 0):

When using the logical "or" operator in an if...else statement in python you have to repeat the variable as well as the value (i know that sounds confusing so look at the example)

this means that this won't work:

```
if order == "Milktea" or "milktea":
```

the correct formation should be:

```
if (order == "Milktea") or (order == "milktea"):
```

alternatively if you want to simply check one variable against a range of values check out the match...case statements in python 3.10+: https://learnpython.com/blog/python-match-case-statement/

######################################################

Remove the if order in mmu line and indent the corresponding else (code listed below)

```
def kuha_order():
while True:
    order = input()
    print(order)
    if order == "Milktea":
        print(flvrs)
        laht.append(order)
        break
    elif order == "Foods":
        print(pgkn)
        laht.append(order)
        break
    elif order == "Drinks":
        print(shot)
        laht.append(order)
        break
    elif order == "Dessert":
        print(mtms)
        laht.append(order)
        break
    else:
        print("Sorry you input a thing that is not available on our menu")
        continue
```

you can combine this with my answer above to get what you need :)

Comment: this does not work also im guessing that maybe the problem is
if order in mnu: this part below the while true and other one

Comment: You don't actually need that statement and it is restricting what inputs are accepted. You can remove this and put the else clause as the else clause of the elif order statements (sorry if that's unclear) - remove the "if order in mmu:" and indent the else clause at the end one more time

Comment: yes is not that clear but im getting your point and i try to remove it but continue outside loop now is the problem  and also Unindent does not match any outer indentation level

Comment: you know the lines:
else:
    print("Sorry you input a thing that is not available on our menu,  "
              "Please Try again:")
        continue
"
 - Indent all of those so that the "else" is on the same level as the "elif" before it

Comment: I'll edit my answer to show you :)

Comment: finallyyy thanks sir its already working lol what i need to do is just put an indent to else im so dumb anyways thank you so muchh i learn the right way on how logical operator should work

Comment: btw you do not need to edit as i read it i finally realized that the if order in mnu is the cause anyways thank you very much since you know i know now the proper way of writing the operator tyty till next time

Comment: hello another little extra question that i forgot how can i make the variable pgln in the top under cstmrinfo only a string because even though i put number it still continue and str(input()) does not work

Comment: hey mate, sorry for the delay - im not quite sure what is happening in your code because all the vars are named wacky things. would u mind editing ur question so that the variable names make more sense? thanks

Comment: okay wait what should i do repost this or just edit on what i post

Comment: so i renamed it the nname variable for Nickname so what i want to do is only to make letters or strings not number but it still continue to the next function when i try to input an umber

Answer (score 0):

You can use either lower() or upper(). Please check the following answer:

```
 if order.lower()=="milktea":
       print(flvrs)
       laht.append(order)
       break
```

OR

```
 if order.upper()=="MILKTEA":
       print(flvrs)
       laht.append(order)
       break
```

Comment: why does it shows error though the error is like this
':' expected

Comment: it shows when i put a double quotation after equal sign

Comment: if statement must have ":"
 @brrtbrrt does not matter if its double quote or single quote.

Please copy paste the code and try it again.

Comment: oh you edited it lol so it shows error just because of the missing 1 equal anyways thank you already find the solution

Comment: yeah, I missed the equal sign. As I was typing from mobile so might be autocorrection deleted one equal sign. Anyways good to know it's working. you can give the thumbs up :)

Comment: i cant though lack reputation lol

Comment: excuse me again another extra little question in the top part the pgln variable part where i will put the name i just want the user or people put a string str(input()) does not work though so how should i do it